# Conditions for constructing a Normal Subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I came upon [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1710506/652014) answer by [pjs36](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/120540/pjs36) while studying normal subgroups, where they state the following theorem:

> Let $G$ be a group, and $H≤G$ a subgroup of G. Then $H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $H$ is a union of conjugacy classes of $G$.

Afterwards the following explanation is offered:

> The above theorem about normal subgroups being a union of conjugacy classes is probably the most elementary way to prove that the alternating group A5 is simple. Its conjugacy class sizes are $1,12,12,15$, and $20$: There are no ways to add these numbers up (including the $1$, for the identity!) and get a divisor of $60$, hence no nontrivial, proper, normal subgroups.

And I began to wonder, for a general finite group $ G $ what are the necessary conditions for a union of its conjugacy classes to become a normal subgroup?

More specifically, let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=n$ and let $\operatorname{Cl}(a)=\{gag^{-1} : g\in G\}$ be the conjugacy class of some $a\in G$.

Then for a set of different class representatives of some size $R=\{e,g_1,g_2,...,g_{r-1}\}\subset G$ where $ 1\leq r\leq n$ let $A=\bigcup_{g_i \in R}\operatorname{Cl}(g_i)$ be the union of their conjugacy classes.

Is it enough for ${\vert A\vert } $ to divide $n$ for it to be a subgroup of $G$, and thus a normal one? Or do we need some other conditions?

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2175828/104041)

Comment: It is certainly not enough for $|A|$ to divide $n$. For example, if that were the case, it would imply that any subset of a finite abelian group $G$ that contains the identity and has order dividing $|G|$ is a subgroup, which is definitely not the case.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That makes sense, for example $\mathbb{Z}_{12}^\times$ is abelian but $\{1,7,11\}$ is not a subgroup since it lacks $7\cdot 11=5\operatorname{mod}12$, while it is a union of conjugacy class since each element is its own class.
Is it possible to find additional conditions that are weaker than outright demanding the Group's definitions to hold?