# If $h$ is the $k$-cycle and g element of $S_n$, prove that $ghg^{-1}=(g(a_1)g(a_2)...g(a_k))$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

$g$ element of $S_n$, prove that $g(a_1   a_2 ...    a_k)g^{-1}=(g(a_1)g(a_2)...g(a_k))$

I'm more concerned with how I can derive the prove of this question

Comment: Please clarify your question: what are $h$ and $a_i$? From the general setting, I assume $a_i$ are transpositions and $h=a_1a_2...a_k$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are two permutations conjugate iff they have the same cycle structure?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48134/why-are-two-permutations-conjugate-iff-they-have-the-same-cycle-structure)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$g(a_1a_2\dots a_k)g^{-1}(g(a_i))=g(a_1a_2\dots a_k)(a_i)=g(a_{i+1})$$