# Cycle types in $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading a group theory book and the author gives the following definition for *cycle type*:

If $\sigma \in S_n$ is the product of disjoint cycles of lengths $n_1,n_2,\ldots ,n_r$ with $n_1 \leq n_2 \leq \cdots \leq n_r$ (including its 1-cycles) then the sequence of integers $n_1, n_2, \ldots ,n_r$ is called the *cycle type* of $\sigma$ where $S_n$ is the symmetric group of degree n.

I'm curious about the significance of the cycle type. If two elements of $S_n$ have the same cycle type are they somehow related?

Comment: Two elements with same cycle type are conjugates. So Their orders will be same as well.

Comment: Yes; two elements of $S_n$ are conjugate to one another if and only if they have the same cycle type. Also, you can determine whether an element of $S_n$ lies in $A_n$ depending on its cycle type, and you can use the cycle type to determine the order of the permutation. It's an important concept.

Comment: I know that you did not ask for a proof, but the answers at the duplicate are so excellent, that it is worth reading them, also for this question.

Comment: You will find a proof of what Arturo wrote in his comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48137/446262), written by… Arturo himself. :-)