# Showing that Klein Four Group is a normal subgroup of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

It is given that $K_4=\{i, (1$ $2)(3$ $4), (1$ $3)(2$ $4), (1$ $4)(2$ $3)\}$.  The question asks me to show that, for $h \in S_4$ and $f \in K_4$,
$$h^{-1}fh\in K_4,$$
using the order of the permutations to deduce the possible cycle-shapes of $h^{-1}fh$. I'm new to group theory so terms like isomorphic  are foreign to me.

Comment: At least you can do it manually or with a computer, since $|S_4|=24$ and you know how to get product of two permutations. (it is not meant to be a clue for solve)

Comment: I'm advised against listing out all the possible products by my lecturer

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that the cycle structure of a permutation is preserved under conjugation.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to show this apart from using a few examples. Is there a formal proof for this?

Comment: You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48134/104041) and [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugate_Permutations_have_Same_Cycle_Type), @Justin.

Comment: Is this line of reasoning correct:
when conjugating 2 permutations, the order follows the 1st permutation. E.g. fg follows the order of g. Following the fact that the order is 2, the possible cycle structure of $h^{-1}fh$ is is $(2^2) or (2, 1^2)$. Since $(2, 1^2)$ is not possible, the cycle structure is $(2^2)$.

Comment: I'm afraid not, @Justin; at least not insofar as I understand what you're saying. I'm not sure what "follows the order of" means. Regardless: what you need to show is that, $$\begin{align}h^{-1}fh&=h^{-1}(ab)(cd)h \\ &=(h(a)h(b))(h(c)h(d)),\end{align}$$ where $h(x)$ is $h$ applied to the underlying element $x\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: @Shaun how do you get from the first to the second line in: $$\begin{align}h^{-1}fh&=h^{-1}(ab)(cd)h \\ &=(h(a)h(b))(h(c)h(d)),\end{align}$$

Comment: I've linked to proofs in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445868/showing-that-klein-four-group-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-s-4/3445876?noredirect=1#comment7083586_3445876), @panzershreks.