# Permutation matrices with trace $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, trace, permutation-matrices

Can we find a characterising property of all the permutation matrices with trace  = $0$?

I know that any traceless matrix is a commutator.
i.e. any traceless matrix $A$ can be written as:-
$$A = PQ-QP$$
for some P and Q.
Also, A being a permutation matrix, is a non-negative orthogonal matrix.
I just wanted to see if we could club all these to give a simple characterization of the traceless permutation matrices in form of an equation.

Comment: your mention of $P^2=I$ is called an involution and that occurs *iff* $P=P^T$. As for your question -- this is the class of traceless permutation matrices, or the class of matrices representing *derangements*

Comment: @user8675309 nicely interpreted! But do they follow any rule as direct as $P^{2} = I$

Comment: So, as you already know traceless permutation matrices are derangements. You can check that composition of permutations is the same as multiplication of their matrices. If you factor a permutation in cycles, the order of the permutation is the lcm of the sizes of the cycles. Take the permutation $(123)(45)$ what is its order? is it $5$?

Comment: @Phicar. No it should be 6. Thanks! So this is sufficient to say that the following rule does not hold. Can you think of an algaebraic property of such kind of matrices?

Comment: @Kabir Indeed! Well, you can check that if your derangement is a cycle, for example $(13542)$ then its order is $5.$ So cycles have that property and you can try to force the length of the cycles to have $lcm =n$ but i do not see a way right now.

Comment: @Phicar Fine! But permutation matrices of our interest are those whose trace  = $0$ Not those with $P^{n} = I$

Comment: @Kabir Well, $P^{\ell}=I_n$ where $\ell$ is the lcm of the cycles of the derangement(traceless permutation matrix).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109573/discussion-between-kabir-and-phicar).

Comment: It's not clear exactly what kind of condition you want. Are you looking for a characterization of such matrices among all matrices, or just among permutation matrices?

Comment: @TravisWillse I want algaebraic equation which could characterize traceless permutation matrices.

Comment: That's clear already but do you want algebraic conditions that so that if $A$ is any matrix (of the right size) then it satisfies the conditions iff $A$ is such a permutation matrix? Or do you want conditions such that of $P$ is a permutation matrix then it satisfies the conditions iff $P$ is tracefree? Either way, $\operatorname{tr} A = 0$ itself is already a compact algebraic condition.

Comment: I wanted algaebraic conditions so that if A is any matrix(of right size) then it satisfies the conditions iff A is a traceless permutation matrix. I wanted such characterization to use in the following problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725338/an-n-times-n-matrix-that-has-exactly-one-1-and-one-1-in-each-row-and-colu

Comment: As you probably know orthogonal matrices are characterized by $A^\top A = I$, so you've almost produced a condition yourself: Namely, $A^\top A = I$, $\min\{a_{ij}\} = 0$, $\operatorname{tr} A = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Permutation matrices can be regarded as "matrix representation" of permutations. Like the permutation matrix $A$ given by,

$A=\pmatrix{ 
0&1&0&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0}$

is a matrix representation of the permutation $\sigma=(123)(45)\in S_5$. Because this permutation is the map
$(1,2,3,4,5)^t\rightarrow A(1,2,3,4,5)^t=(\sigma1,\sigma2,\sigma3,\sigma4,\sigma5)$.

If we denote the matrix of the permutation $\sigma$ by $P_{\sigma}$, then we can get $M_{\sigma}M_{\rho}=M_{\sigma \rho}$.

Now if a permutation matrix $P$ of order $n$ has trace zero, then its corresponding permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ has no fixed point. Hence if
$\sigma=c_1c_2\dots c_k$ is the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{k}l(c_i)=n$.

Now as mentioned in the above comment, the permutation matrix $A=M_{\sigma}$ of $\sigma=(123)(45)$ has trace zero and $A^5=M_{\sigma^5}$. But $M_{\sigma^5}=I_5$ implies $ \sigma^5$ is identity permutation, which is not true, since $o(\sigma)=6$.  Thus $A^5\neq I_5$.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! But that does not helps us characterizing the traceless permutation matrices.

Comment: Yes, this answer was to contradict your previous claim and an insight about traceless matrix.