# If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$ containing a transposition, show that $H=S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$ containing a transposition, show that $H=S_n$.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? Most group theory textbook should covers this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every two transpositions are conjugate. So if a normal subgroup contains one of them it contains all of them and so the whole symmetric group is equal to the normal subgroup.

Comment: What do you mean by "every two transpositions are conjugate"?

Comment: @chickenwing72 More generally, any elements of $S_n$ with the same cycle structure [are conjugate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48134/why-are-two-permutations-conjugate-iff-they-have-the-same-cycle-structure).