# Conjugated elements of $S_n$ for $n\geq 1.$

Tags: permutation-cycles

**If $n\geq 5.$ Prove  for all $(ab)(cde)$ of $S_n$  (with different $a,b,c,d,e$) are conjugated.**

My proof is the following:

Given $\alpha=(a_1b_1)(c_1d_1e_1)$ y $\beta=(a_2b_2)(c_2d_2e_2)$, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha(a_1)&=&b_1\\
\alpha(b_1)&=&a_1\\
\alpha(c_1)&=&d_1\\
\alpha(d_1)&=&e_1\\
\alpha(e_1)&=&c_1\\
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\beta(a_2)&=&b_2\\
\beta(b_2)&=&a_2\\
\beta(c_2)&=&d_2\\
\beta(d_2)&=&e_2\\
\beta(e_2)&=&c_2\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Given two cycles $(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,e_1)$ y $(a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2,e_2)$,  consider the following permutation $\sigma:$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma(a_1)&=&a_2\\
\sigma(b_1)&=&b_2\\
\sigma(c_1)&=&c_2\\
\sigma(d_1)&=&d_2\\
\sigma(e_1)&=&e_2\\
\end{eqnarray*}
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma\alpha\sigma^{-1}(a_2)&=&\sigma \alpha(a_1)=\sigma(b_1)=b_2,\\
\sigma\alpha\sigma^{-1}(b_2)&=&\sigma \alpha(b_1)=\sigma(a_1)=a_2,\\
\sigma\alpha\sigma^{-1}(c_2)&=&\sigma \alpha(c_1)=\sigma(d_1)=d_2,\\
\sigma\alpha\sigma^{-1}(d_2)&=&\sigma 
\alpha(d_1)=\sigma(e_1)=e_2,\\
\sigma\alpha\sigma^{-1}(e_2)&=&\sigma \alpha(e_1)=\sigma(c_1)=c_2.
\end{eqnarray*}

What do you think about this proof?

Comment: Why do you have doubts?

Comment: A very picky point. As $n$ may not be exactly $5$ you need to say where $\sigma$ sends the points which are not $a_1,\dots, e_1$.

Comment: You are right, $n$ is not necessarily  5.

Comment: Do you know what inner automorphisms are? I ask the question, because if the answer is positive, you could make a proof at a higher and simpler level.

Comment: So to complete your proof you need to define $\sigma$ on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}\setminus\{a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,e_1\}$

Comment: A very enlightning explanation of conjugation can be found at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48137/305862) to a similar question.