# Finding an unknown permutation when given the product with a known permutation.

Tags: notation, permutation-cycles

I have a permutation$f \in S_7$ with $|f| = 6$ and $h \in S_7$ with $|h| = 6$.
I need to find a permutation, $j \in S_7$, such that $h=jfj^{-1}$.

$$
h =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 6 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 3 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\\
$$
$$
f =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 4 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 7 & 3 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I tried writing both permutations as a product of transpositions and solving to find j but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48134) (and your permutations are not cycles).

Comment: Thank you and I'll correct that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint that might be useful to you is the following lemma.

> *Lemma:* If $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$ with $\sigma = (a_1 \dots a_k)$ then $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (\tau(a_1)\dots \tau(a_k))$.

Proving this isn't terribly difficult, and it can be leveraged with a little trick here. Note that in cycle notation your permutations may be written as $h = (16)(247)(35)$ and $f = (14)(263)(57)$. We want to find $j$ where
\begin{align*}
h &= jfj^{-1}\\
(16)(247)(35) & = j(14)(263)(57)j^{-1}
\end{align*}
The standard trick here is to multiply by $1 = j^{-1}j$ between each of the terms so as to get the conjugates of each cycle in the decomposition of $f$, namely
$$
(16)(247)(35) = j(14)j^{-1}j(263)j^{-1}j(57)j^{-1}
$$
then by applying the lemma we get
$$
(16)(247)(35) = (j(1)j(4))(j(2)j(6)j(3))(j(5)j(7)).
$$
With this you can match up the terms to get that $j = (1)(2)(375)(46) = (375)(46)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)